# android: get string with correct encoding from web service

Tags: php, android, web-services, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying get string result from PHP webservice in my android application, I used [ksaop2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library and this is my code :

```
env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = false;
env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
request = new SoapObject("customWebService","addProductToCart");
request.addProperty("sessionID", sessionId);
request.addProperty("cartID", cartID);
request.addProperty("productID", productID);
request.addProperty("qty", qty);
request.addProperty("sku", productSKU);
env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
    "http://mysiteeee.com/WebServiceSOAP/server.php?wsdl/",
    60000);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

result = env.getResponse();
```

It`s returned this:

```
???·???§?? ?¯?²?????? (???§??) ?§???²?§???? ???­?µ???? ?±?§ ???´?®?µ ?©?????¯.
```

I tested it on Chrome and Firefox with UTF-8 encoding and shows result correctly on browser.

How can I get result from web service with correct encoding and show it on android?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting response this way :

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
// Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
String Test1 = result.getProperty(0).toString();
```

**Edit** : Try setting Xml header Tag for request :

```
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Comment: now it return me this : addProductToCartResponse{return=???·???§?? ?¯?²?????? (???§??) ?§???²?§???? ???­?µ???? ?±?§ ???´?®?µ ?©?????¯.; }

Comment: @mahdi : plz see the edited answer , hope it changes the response

Comment: The response did not change.

Comment: i have this problem on send and receive string with Unicode.

Comment: @mahdi : i don't think that there is any other way to get response right in android. probably the webservice part cause the issue.